# C# & VS2015: How to save time when compiling?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, compiler-optimization

So, I have a BIG project with lots of stuff in it, but when for example I fix the code, VS2015 compiles the whole project again which takes lots and lots of time. Can I somehow only compile the file I edited?
EDIT: I have one solution, in that I have one project, in that project I have lots of files.

Comment: Something tells me that your project is too big and should be broken to subprojects. One project produces *one* binary so you can't avoid rebuilding that binary if one file changes.

Comment: Do you mean 1 project with lots of files or 1 solution with lots of projects?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have one solution, that has one project, that has lots of files in it.

Comment: Then my answer won't help.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen But can I speed up it if I only use one project?

Comment: No, you cannot, not other than doing what others here have answered, like splitting up the project.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So... if I split up my project, your answer will work?

Comment: Yes, it would, but then you may not need it, because as others have hinted here, Visual Studio already does *some* optimization. Either way I have deleted my answer as it does not answer the question asked.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Please undelete it. It was the best response.

Comment: It was a good and detailed response, and I upvoted it. Hope you can add it to some other question :-) but less applicable for the single-project scenario here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Build process is smart, it will skip projects that haven't changed and for which the dependencies also haven't been changed. If you change something inside a library that is used by more or less the entire solution, then there just is no alternative but to rebuild all that was (potentially) touched.

You could try tuning the Dependencies yourself, right-click on the Solution and select 'Project dependencies...'. But you can't remove Dependencies that are needed or inferred.

Comment: In Visual Studio a Project is either built completely, or skipped completely. The output is a DLL (assembly) and a DLL can't be patched to 'inject only the changes', it has to be rebuilt. As others have already suggested it may prove valuable to divide your large project up into a number of smaller projects. Good luck doing so!

Comment: I have one project in the solution... but if I split it up it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Get an SSD as build drive. A fast one.

All the other tips given here are a given - build is smart, so it will only recompile what needs to be recompiled. This is hardly a help, though, if you have a base library that triggers dozens of projects to update.

Compilation is IO limited, so a SSD helps

Otherwise it may be time to destroy that large solution and generate inernal NUGET packages of base libraries. This can decouple recompilations of base libraries and actual applications. This is particularly useful if you do maintenance on the base libraries.